# Bubble sort algorithm implementing

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, bubble-sort

I'm learning the bubble sort algorithm and i came across 2 ways of implementing it so my question is which is better and why?

1st

```
for(k=0;k<array.length-1;k++){ 
            if(array[k] > array[k+1]){
                int temp = array[k];
                array[k] = array[k+1];
                array[k+1] = temp;
            }
        }
```

---

2nd

```
for(i=array.length-1;i>=0;i--){
        for(k=0;k<i;k++){ 
            if(array[k] > array[k+1]){
                int temp = array[k];
                array[k] = array[k+1];
                array[k+1] = temp;
            }
        }
        }
```

Comment: 1st one won't sort the array.

Comment: Second one is better because it sort the given array.

Answer (score 1):

More than about which one is better - first of all its about which one sorts the array and the answer is **2nd one**

check [this](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/data/arrays/32arraybubblesort.html) to get more idea

Answer (score 0):

1st of your implementation not make correctly sorting becouse the algorithm can switch only 2 adjoining elements.

Ex.

input data {6,5,4,3,2}

first iteration make this -> {5,6,4,3,2} and now 5 is on 1st position and has no chance to change this position, becouse loop index(k) is 1. And further iteration it increases..

Bubble sort need 2 loops always

```
public static void bubbleSort(int[] array){
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array.length - i - 1; j++) {
            if(array[j] < array[j+1]){
                int tmp = array[j];
                array[j] = array[j+1];
                array[j+1] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found more efficient ones in Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort)

```
procedure bubbleSort( A : list of sortable items )
    n = length(A)
    repeat
       newn = 0
       for i = 1 to n-1 inclusive do
          if A[i-1] > A[i] then
             swap(A[i-1], A[i])
             newn = i
           end if
       end for
       n = newn
    until n = 0
end procedure
```

Answer (score 0):

The second one will sort the array. But you can reduce the comparisons in second loop by running it only when there is at least a single swap in last iteration.

Comment: That way you can reduce best case complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Your first solution won't work it will not sort the array. But the second, will work and it will sort data starting from the smallest to the biggest. For more explanation, see below:

Well, the idea behind bubble sort algorithm is to go through the      array/collection of data while comparing each pair of adjacent items and       swapping them if they are in the wrong order. The pass through the array/list is repeated until no swaps are needed, which indicates that the list/array is sorted.
Time Complexity: O(n^2). and the space we will use the original array. Let use the following array the illustrate the talk in above paragraph:

```
    //array of integer to be sorted
    int[] arrayToSort=new int[]{1,7,81,2,-2,9,9,6,-6};
    //repeat until we're done sorting 
    while (true){
        //flag to check if we did swap number(s)
        boolean didSort=false;
        /*
         *  this inner loop is being used to find numbers that need to be    
         *  swapped and then help in swapping them
         */
        for(int count=0;count<arrayToSort.length-1;count++){
            //check if we need to swap
            if(arrayToSort[count]>arrayToSort[count+1]){
                int temp=arrayToSort[count+1];
                arrayToSort[count+1]=arrayToSort[count];
                arrayToSort[count]=temp;
                //set our swap flag so that we will know that we did swap
                didSort=true;
            }

        }

        //check we did a swap in our last inner loop iteration if not will   
        //be done sorting, then break the outer loop
        if(!didSort){
            break;
        }   
    }

    //let's print the sorted array.
    for(int i=0;i<arrayToSort.length;i++){
        System.out.print(arrayToSort[i]+", ");
    }
```

Comment: While this is an answer, could you expand on it a little? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score -2):

Don't use bubblesort (use insertion sort instead).

EDIT:

Since people keep down-voting this, please read http://warp.povusers.org/grrr/bubblesort_misconceptions.html

Bubblesort is Pareto-inefficiënt, since it is both slower and more difficult to understand than for example insertionsort and selectionsort. Just don't use (nor teach) Bubblesort.